# How to avoid huge setup scripts?

Tags: magento2, setup-script

The approach I've seen so far to handle setup scripts is the version_compare:

```
namespace My\Module\Setup;

class UpgradeSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
{

    public function __construct(
        \My\Module\Model\SomethingFactory $somethingFactory,
        \My\Module\Model\AnotherThing $anotherThing
    ) {
        $this->somethingFactory = $somethingFactory;
        $this->anotherThing = $anotherThing;
    }

    public function upgrade(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0', '<')) {
            // do stuff with $this->somethingFactory
        }

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            // do stuff with $this->anotherThing
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

}
```

At some point in the life of a module, those scripts can become huge and very hard to maintain, and the dependencies injected might change over time, but you'll need to keep all of them in order to guarantee a safe upgrade from each particular version you have published.

Is it known any other possible approach to manage the setup scripts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Split it to set of classes.

Like UpdaterTo100, UpdaterTo101, ...

Comment: Any examples? How do I tell Magento to read those files?